# Bayes Rule and conditional probability question

Tags: probability, bayes-theorem

Incorporating evidence

You roll a weighted die and intend to observe the number of spots X. You know
that, due to the weighting, higher numbers are more likely: in particular,
P(X = x) = (x + 2) / 33 for x from 1 to 6.

The die rolls under the table, so that you can't see it. However, a friend tells
you that the number of spots is even. You know that your friend is not that
reliable: he only tells the truth about this sort of thing with probability 3/4 , and
lies with probability 1
/4 . What is the probability that X = 5 given the evidence
above? Hint: use Bayes rule to incorporate the noisy observation of the die
roll. You can use the version where you don't need to know the denominator
ahead of time; instead you can calculate the denominator using the fact that
probabilities must sum to 1.

I'm going along the first comment and calculate the joint as P(S|X=5) * P(X=5) which equals 1/4 * 7/33. Given everything computed so far I've reached the final answer P(X=5|S) = 7/69. Is this correct?

Comment: **Possible outline:**  Let $E$ be the event that the die shows even, and $S$ be the event your friend says it shows even. (a) It is easy to find $P(E) = 6/11.$
(b) $P(S) = (3/4)P(E) + (1/4)P(E^c).$  (c) $P(X=5|S) = P(\{X=5\} \cap S)/P(S).$

Comment: instead of copying verbatim the hint that your textbook (or wherever the problem came) provides, you could include some of your own thoughts on the problem; this will be more helpful to those who want to help you, and will also let them know that they are actually helping you, not just doing your homework.

Comment: Thanks! I've added some of my progress.